# How to select object randomly from vector in c++

Tags: c++, random, vector

I have a vector : 
`std::vector<const City*> cities`

I want to write a funtion which will return me another vector with same type but in which the position of objects will be taken randomly.

```
std::vector<const City*> TSP::rand_cities() const  { }
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Create a copy of the original vector, apply `std::random_shuffle` and return it.

Comment: Or you could consider implementing the [Fisher Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), if you want to write the function yourself (the question seems to indicate that you want to write it yourself).  Just make sure to use a proper shuffling algorithm and that you use a good random number generator.

Comment: I tried  std::random_shuffle and get this error  could not convert 'std::random_shuffle<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const City* const*, std::vector<const City*> > >(((const TSP*)this)-
  >TSP::cities.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<const City*, std::allocator<const City*> >(), ((const TSP*)this)->TSP::cities.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<const 
  City*, std::allocator<const City*> >())' from 'void' to 'std::vector<const City*>'

Comment: @kerrachemassipssa It looks like you tried `return std::random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());`. What you want is `std::random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end()); return vec;` Where `vec` is my stand-in for whatever your vector is named.

Comment: It's what I did but it didn't work.

Comment: The error message you posted says you tried to convert the `void` from `std::random_shuffle` to `vector`. Somewhere out there you have a `vec = std::random_shuffle(...)`. Here's a link to some reputable `random_shuffle` documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle . Something is going wrong and maybe a refresher can help.